# MVC View - how to display the "category" of objects collection, not just the objects themselves

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP MVC and Entity Framework.  In the view, you have a page declaration that specifies the model for this view will be a collection implementing IEnumerable.  Let's say that collection holds Car objects, that are only from Ford (Ford being the Category).

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<detelete.Models.Car>>" %>
```

This list of Ford cars only, was generated via a LINQ to Entities query.  The EF object thingee is aware of the relationship of Cars to Manufacturers (which I call the category)

```
            var dat = ent.CarSet.Where(m => m.Manufacturer.Name == nm);

        List<Car> cars = dat.ToList<Car>();
        return View("ListingByManufacturer", cars);
```

So, in the view I display the list of cars that are all Ford's.  I have the view displaying all the cars properties correctly, but there isn't a way to show what category (manufacturer in this example) the **cars are from**.  I have seen some EF/MVC examples that have two foreach loops, and the top one displays the manufacturer - but that feels klugey.

Seems like it should be simple, but I am stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the Manufacturer name via `ViewData` in the controller :

```
ViewData["Manufacturer"] = nm;
```

Or use a another object as your model that holds both cars and the manufacturer name

```
public class CategoryViewModel {
     public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
     public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

And pass an instance of that class to the view.

Comment: I prefer the model option instead of muddying up ViewData with unnecessary strings.  This would be a "ViewModel".  They are separated from your actual data model, and exist solely to provide convenience to your view.

Comment: ViewModel.  That looks like a perfect fit for this problem. I have been telling myself, 'once you get a handle on asp.net mvc, you need to look into the current wars over Views and ViewModels'.